# NullPointerException on SharedPreferences (Seems to be the context)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm just getting started with Android Studio, currently trying to make a simple app that lets you take notes and save them, maybe some 'to do list' features. I'm trying to store them in SharedPreferences using Json / Gson. Followed some online tutorials but can't seem to get it to work. Similar questions on here didn't help either. This is my code so far:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NoteHandler noteHandler = new NoteHandler();
        noteHandler.newNote("test", 1);
    }

}
```

Note.java:

```
public class Note {

    public enum State { TODO, DONE };

    private String content;
    private State state;
    private Date date;
    private int id;
    private Note parent;

    public Note(String content, State state, Date date, Note parent, int id) {
        this.content = content;
        this.state = state;
        this.date = date;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.id = id;
    }

    /* Getters and setters */

}
```

NoteHandler.java:

```
public class NoteHandler {

    NotePrefs notePrefs = new NotePrefs(ContextGetter.getAppContext());

    void newNote(String content, int id) {
        newNote(content, null, id);
    }

    void newNote(String content, Note parent, int id) {
        Note newNote = new Note(content, Note.State.TODO, new Date(), parent, id);
        notePrefs.saveNote(newNote);
    }

    Note getNote(int id) {
        return notePrefs.loadNote(id);
    }
}
```

NotePrefs.java:

```
public class NotePrefs {
    private final String PREFS_NAME = "notes.NotePrefs";
    private static SharedPreferences settings;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static Gson gson = new Gson();

    public NotePrefs(Context ctx) {
        if(settings == null) {
            settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }

        editor = settings.edit();
    }

    public static void saveNote(Note note) {
        editor.putString("" + note.getId(), gson.toJson(note));
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static Note loadNote(int id) {
        String noteJson = settings.getString("" + id, "");
        return gson.fromJson(noteJson, Note.class);
    }

    public static List<Note> loadAllNotes() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

ContextGetter.java:

```
public class ContextGetter extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

The exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{notes/notes.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Still can't seem to wrap my head around the context stuff. Any help is appreciated!

Also, what's a good way to implement loadAllNotes()?

Cheers

Comment: Hm, seems this `ContextGetter` is not working properly. Why can't you just pass the instance of the activity as the `context` to your `NoteHandler` and then to the `NotePrefs`?

Comment: The other comment made it work already. What exactly did you suggest though, can you write it in code? I really have no idea about activities and contexts (yet)...

Comment: Please post the stacktrace. Also what line causes the NPE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `name=".ContextGetter"` to manifest in `<application>` tag.

Comment: Wow, that actually did the trick! I'm glad it wasn't some stupid mistake on my part. Thank you! Can you tell me what exactly that line does or why it made everything work?

Comment: Your welcome. Without these lines your class which extends application is never be created. Please accept answer